# systemd: get core dumps for service started by xinetd

Tags: xinetd, systemd, dump

I recently upgraded a system to openSUSE 13.1. We're running a custom-built service on the system through xinetd, and in the old xinetd init script had the line `ulimit -c unlimited` before starting xinetd to enable core dumps. Since openSUSE 13.1 uses systemd, this does not work anymore.

`systemd-coredumpctl` does not find any core dumps even though there are kernel log messages that confirm the crashes. Starting the service manually from bash and then sending it SIGSEGV does create a core dump in the directory we configured. How do I get my core dumps back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out systemd supports setting limits in the configuration files, the information is just scattered throughout various man pages. According to [systemd.exec](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html), the limit for core dump creation / file size is set with LimitCORE. Additionally, it is possible to modify a unit / service configuration without having to modify the system-provided config file. More information in the [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Editing_provided_unit_files). So creating the file (and parent directory) `/etc/systemd/system/xinetd.service.d/core.conf` with the following content

```
[Service]
LimitCORE=infinity
```

and then executing

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl restart xinetd
```

activated the changes needed for creating core dumps.